# display ASCII characters

Tags: c, char

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CHAR_SET 256

void  main ( void )
{
    int i;
    #if CHAR_SET ==256
        printf("display full ASCII character set plus extension" );
    #else 
        printf("displaying only ASCII charaters set ")
    #endif 

    printf("\n");
    for (i=0; i<CHAR_SET; i++)
        printf("%c", i);
}
```

When I try to compile it the following error occurs: 
In function ‘main’:
char.c:6: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Your code doesn't indent properly.

Answer (score 4):

Change it to `int main` and end it with `return 0`.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to make your definition of main returns `int`, eg:

```
int main(void)
```

Then, you'll need to make sure you put `return 0` at the end of your function.

Returning `EXIT_SUCCESS` (usually `0`) from `main()` indicates your program was successful, and `EXIT_FAILURE` indicates failure. See [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function#C_and_C.2B.2B) for more details.

Comment: "extra question marks for min answer length" - I would have put more in.